# Custom meta query filter for WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to filter my products with custom post `meta_key` for **`"_city_name"`**, as well as the keyword **`"s"`** with **`AND`** operation currently I'm doing in my `functions.php`:

```
function my_modify_main_query( $query ) {

    $meta_query_args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_city_name',
                'value' => 'new york',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        )
    );
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query_args);
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_modify_main_query' );
```

It's working if I don't add keyword in the GET params **`"s"`**.

But if I add keyword `"s=beer&city=newyork"`, it stop working.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> First you need to **always return something in a filter hooked function** at the end:

```
return $query;
```

---

May be you should include `$_GET['city']` for `'value'` this way: `'value' => $_GET['city'],` instead. But you will need to check before `$_GET['city']` value.

So your code should be:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_modify_main_query' );
function my_modify_main_query( $query ) {

    // Checking for "city" data
    if( ! isset( $_GET['city'] ) ) return $query;

    $meta_query_args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_city_name',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['city'] ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        )
    );
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query_args);

    return $query; ## <==== This was missing
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

I didn't test it, but it should work.